# How could I plot stock price (high and low) as a stick for each day in R?

Tags: r

There are two vectors high and low with the highest and lowest prices respectively, how could I plot them as a stick for each day? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `segments` to plot the sticks, but you need to set up a reasonable space for them to be plotted.

```
## Some bogus data
Time = 1:20
set.seed(2017)
Low = round(13 + Time/4 + rnorm(20)/2, 2)
High = round(Low + 2 + rnorm(20)/2)

## Get limits and plot
LL = floor(min(Low))
UL = ceiling(max(High))
plot(NA, xlim=c(1,20), ylim=c(LL,UL), ylab="Range")
segments(1:20,Low, 1:20, High)
```

[image: Highs and Lows]

Comment: Thank you very much